# Redis client GetAll keys from a certain class

Tags: c#, redis, servicestack

I have a redis with many keys (around 100), I want to select only Keys from type of ClassA (just an example).

Right now I am doing GetAllKeys, and then going in a foreach loop on all items and selecting just the relevant keys.

Is it possible to select just the relevant keys and get them all with one function?

When I am doing GetAll I get only 2 items while I should get around 45.

Comment: Don't do this. Redis is not a relational database. You are not supposed to use the KEYS command in applications - it is more a debug command. This design will not scale with Redis.

Answer (score 4):

Following code will help you to find specific key,you have to specify `*` wildcard character after string, will only fetch specific keys from Redis Server.

```
 using (RedisClient redisClient = new RedisClient("localhost"))
 {
      string searchString = "ClassA*";

      var getSpecificKeys = redisClient.SearchKeys(searchString);

      foreach (var getKey in getSpecificKeys)
      {
           // operation
      }
  }
```

Comment: From http://redis.io/commands/keys
Warning: consider KEYS as a command that should only be used in production environments with extreme care. It may ruin performance when it is executed against large databases. This command is intended for debugging and special operations, such as changing your keyspace layout. Don't use KEYS in your regular application code. If you're looking for a way to find keys in a subset of your keyspace, consider using sets.

Comment: What if I use IDatabase instead of RedisClient? How can I get all the keys in the db?